# How is the electron (&ion) temperature measured in plasmas using Langmuir probes?

Tags: plasma-physics

I want to know the concept behind the temperature measurement and what exactly the "probe" does apart from introducing potential in the plasma.

Also, while deriving an expression for electron temperature in terms of electron saturation current, why is the J integrated from V(thermal) to infinity?
And what exactly is the thermal velocity in this case?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langmuir_probe is a reasonable place to start. Where do you run into trouble?

Comment: I've seen a lot of resources on the web but haven't found anything that gives a proper explanation and a derivation to go with the explanation to cement the concept properly.

Comment: Well, one problem is what a 'proper' explanation is to you vs somebody else. I spent time many moons ago looking at what a probe in a plasma might do, given the ions and electrons with different masses and velocity distributions. That ended up being 'proper' for me, but your mileage may vary. As it stands, this question is likely too broad.

Comment: Anything at the elementary/introductory level will do for now.... I just need some math to back up the theory to get an idea. I found a few good sources for theory part

Answer (score 1):

Like [Jon Custer said](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/489555/how-is-the-electron-ion-temperature-measured-in-plasmas-using-langmuir-probes?rq=1#comment1101266_489555), this is a very broad question and there exists many explanations about what a Langmuir probe is and how it works. Instead of trying to give a lengthy explanation here, I forward you to some references. Read them, study them, re-read them and you might find an answer to your questions. If you have any detailed question after working through this literature list, feel free to ask them here.

- *Principles of Plasma Diagnostics (Second Edition)*, Ian Hutchinson, Chapter 3 (Plasma Particle Flux) (Cambridge University Press, 2002)
- [*Lecture Notes on Langmuir Probe Diagnostics*, Francis F. Chen (Mini-Course on Plasma Diagnostics, IEEE-ICOPS meeting, Jeju, Korea, 2003)](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/~ffchen/Publs/Chen210R.pdf)
- [*Understanding Langmuir probe current-voltage characteristics*, Robert L. Melino, doi:10.1119/1.2772282](https://dx.doi.org/10.1119/1.2772282)
- [*Sheaths and Langmuir Probes (Lecture: Physics 386K - Plasma Diagnostics)*, Kenneth Gentle](https://web2.ph.utexas.edu/~phy315/Sensors3.Probes.pdf)